# Движение элементов

Tags: html, css

При наведение на тег a двигаются нижние элементы. Не могу разобраться почему так происходит, вроде виноват scale, но не знаю как решить проблему. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

```css
 li { list-style-type: none;}
 .content { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 580px;}
 .menu { 
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  transition: background-color .4s linear;
  
  color: #fff; 
  overflow: hidden; }
 .menu:hover { 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
  transition: background-color .4s linear; }
 li {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 66px;

  box-sizing: border-box; }
 .link {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer; 
  letter-spacing: 1px; 
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: transform .4s linear;
  filter: blur(0px); }
 .link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(129, 6, 29, 0.8); 
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .4s linear;
  filter: blur(0px); }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
   <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
   <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
   <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
   <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
   <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь в  `.menu` вот эти строки:

```
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility
```

Получится вот так:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 580px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color .4s linear;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility
}

.menu:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: background-color .4s linear;
}

li {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 66px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: transform .4s linear;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(129, 6, 29, 0.8);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .4s linear;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">Пункт</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вроде это какой-то извечный баг вебкита https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23364

что-то описано про это тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278587/webkit-text-flickers-when-using-css-transform-scale/12377920#12377920

---

P.S. Но с данным решением ЕМНИП тоже не всё гладко и есть подводные камни. Но я не помню какие))

Comment: Так и знал надо было в свое время задать этот вопрос)